# Take screenshot of second monitor with python on OSX

Tags: python, macos, screenshot

I am trying to make an ambient light system with Python. I have gotten [pyscreenshot](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyscreenshot) to save a screenshot correctly, but I can't figure out how to get it to screenshot my second monitor (if this is even possible).

Is there a way to take a screenshot of my second monitor in Python using pyscreenshot (or something else)? I am using OSX Yosemite if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 6):

Use the built-in `screencapture` command and pass it 2 filenames. I believe it lives in `/usr/sbin/screencapture` so the command will look like this:

```
/usr/sbin/screencapture screen1.png screen2.png
```

I assume you know how to shell out to it using the `subprocess` module, along these lines

```
from subprocess import call
call(["/usr/sbin/screencapture", "screen1.png", "screen2.png"])
```

Answer (score 0):

[Mark Setchell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30040375/141818) is correct.  Also this can't be done with `pyscreenshot` directly.  If you look at [the source](https://github.com/ponty/pyscreenshot/blob/master/pyscreenshot/plugins/mac_screencapture.py), you'll notice that on Mac OSX they do use the `screencapture` utility but only pass it one file as an argument.  The documentation (`man screencapture`) says that you have to pass in as many files as there are screens:

> *files* – where to save the screen capture, 1 file per screen